# mounting usb stick -says path to stick doesn't exist or isn't a directory

Tags: usb, mount

I don't know much about linux and I've been trying to mount a usb-stick.
I looked at all the post and followed the instructions.
I can find the stick with blkid

```
/dev/sdf1: LABEL_FATBOOT="DIANE M" UUID="9A20-C14F" TYPE="vfat"
```

I can find it with fdisk -l

```
Schijf /dev/sdf: 14,92 GiB, 16000221184 bytes, 31250432 sectoren
Disk model: Cruzer Slice    
Eenheid: sectoren van 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sectorgrootte (logisch/fysiek): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
In-/uitvoergrootte (minimaal/optimaal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Schijflabeltype: dos
Schijf-ID: 0x00000000

Apparaat   Op. Begin    Einde Sectoren Grootte ID Type
/dev/sdf1         32 31250431 31250400   14,9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA
```

When I remove the usb this info is no longer available.

But when I try to mount it, I get an error message

```
sudo mount /dev/sdf/ /media/USB-drive
   EM : device /dev/sdf/ doesn't exist  (the path contains somthing that isn't a directory / folder)
```

I've  translated from Dutch. By the way, USB-drive is the directory I created inside media.

I've tried this variation :
`sudo mount /dev/sdf/sdf1 /media/USB-drive`

I've got ubuntu 20.04 installed on a desktop and again on a laptop. The laptop recognizes the stick, I can write to it. The desktop does not. I've been having this issue for some time with my desktop. I was able to mount it before, now it doesn't work.
Though I've got the same version of ubuntu on both pc's, they appear different. On  the laptop there's this list I can choose from in the middle of the screen, on the desktop there's only a list on the left side of  the screen. My launcher is empty since I upgraded it two days ago. I have to go into software or snap store to find an application that is not attached to the left sidebar. Don't know if that is at all related to the issue with the stick. (that I really do want resolved).

Thank you

Comment: Try `/dev/sdf1` - exactly as shown in the `blkid` / `fdisk` output

Comment: did you create the mountpoint /media/USB-drive before you try to mount it?

Comment: yes I did. I followed instructions I found on https://www.fosslinux.com/44371/how-to-mount-usb-drive-in-linux.htm

Comment: I have tried /dev/sdf1 and dev/sdf/sdf1 and /dev/sdf  - nothing works- the EM is identical

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld /media/USB-drive` If this outputs nothing, try `ls -l /media/` ...

Comment: *"the EM is identical "* that suggests you are adding a `/` to the end - please be sure to type `/dev/sdf1` **not** `/dev/sdf1/`

Comment: YES, that works. Such a small detail. Thank you very much, I can look at the files now. It's solved, is there something I click to confirm that?

Comment: the output of ls -ld /media/USB-drive is 
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 8192 jan  1  1970 /media/USB-drive

but as I posted already, I got in, I missed a slash. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu, there should not be a need to mount a USB stick using the terminal. By default, USB sticks are automounted when you plug them in.

That a stick does not automount rather points to an issue with the stick. It could designate problems with the file system. Thus, before attempting anything else, have your file system checked. You can check it with `fsck`. If the file system is not too badly damaged, linux will recognize it is a FAT32 formatted system (as you also see in the first output you posted), and invoke `fsck.vfat` to check it.

Your drive is known as `/dev/sdf`. The partition that is existing on it, is known as `/dev/sdf1`. You should only check a partition that is not in use, so to be safe, you first unmount it, as administrator:

```
sudo umount /dev/sdf1
```

Then you can check it:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdf1
```

This will report on any issues and inconsistencies that may be there. In order to effectively repair the file system, allowing the system choose what to do, you execute the command again with the `-a` option (see `man fsck.vfat` to learn about all possible options).

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdf1
```

Once that is done, wait a few seconds and then unplug the USB. Plug it back in - it should automount.

Your question actually was on how to mount it on the terminal. Again, prefer to rely on the automatic system, but if you really wish to mount manually, then you can using the `mount` command executed as administrator.

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdf1 /media/USB-drive
```

Here, indeed, you state you want to mount the partition `/dev/sdf1` on the folder  `/media/USB-drive`. For this command to proceed, the folder that will be the mount point must already exist. If needed, create it with the command `sudo mkdir /media/USB-drive`.

Comment: I followed your instructions and I got this:
``` 
'fsck' uit util-linux 2.34
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
0x41: Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt.
1) Remove dirty bit
2) No action
? 1
There are differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  71:44/4e, 72:49/4f, 73:41/20, 75:45/41, 76:20/4d, 77:4d/45
1) Copy original to backup
2) Copy backup to original
3) No action
? 1
Perform changes ? (y/n) y
/dev/sdf1: 287 files, 1090/1951102 clusters
```

Comment: I sai yes to it, took it out, put it back in but no it doesn't automount. I used to in the past and after some update no longer. I have the problem with other sticks as well, it seems one after the other is getting corrupted somehow. The stick works, then it doesn't anymore, another one works and then no more.

Comment: So this confirms what I suspected: you are dealing with a damaged file system. Such file systems may not anymore properly automount. To avoid file systems on sticks going down, you have to unplug them carefully, using software first, each and every time.

Comment: THANK YOU. It may be best to reinstall the ubuntu 20 from scratch?
I have found a post https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-repair.html.en on how to repair it, I'll go over that. THANK YOU it's good to know my pc is sick. I can do something about it now.

Comment: Really? For a damaged file system??? Repair it, eventually reformat it instead, and then be careful in handling it. Reinstalling an OS will not make up for improperly handling a USB.

Comment: will do so. thanks again